# basic function in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, function, jscript

Hi this is my very first time here and I'm struggling since I'm first timer learning to code. 
I presume when I try to pass the arguments to the parameters, it gets confused, or maybe I'm missing something very simple. Where am I missing or failing here? I just doesn't work...

```
  function adultCheck(age,name) {
  if (age <= 17) {
    alert("Sorry " + name ", you are not allowed to see this, you are too young.");
  } else {
    alert("Welcome " + name ", you are " + age "  visit our lounge!");
  }

}

adultCheck(15,Tami);
```

Comment: Your function has some missing items like `+` after `name` as you're concatenating strings and variables. Also you should quote the name when using it in the function call. Finally, have you put the code in valid HTML with the correct script/javascript declaration?

Comment: Some of the more basic errors like these can be resolved pretty handily by inspecting the results in your browser's Developer Console (usually accessible by pressing F12). It may even save you a later trip to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also forgot to add an additional + after the variables:  "" + name + ""

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `+` signs around the `name` and `age` concatenations in your function, and you should add quotes to your string. Like,

```js
function adultCheck(age, name) {
  if (age <= 17) {
    alert("Sorry " + name + ", you are not allowed to " 
          + "see this, you are too young.");
  } else {
    alert("Welcome " + name + ", you are " + age 
          + " visit our lounge!");
  }
}
adultCheck(15, 'Tami');
```

Comment: Yes!! I knew it was simple mistakes!! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your second parameter should be a string, so it needs to be in quotes:

```
adultCheck(15, "Tami");
```

Also, you're missing a couple of `+` symbols around your variables:

```
function adultCheck(age, name) {
  if (age <= 17) {
    alert("Sorry " + name + ", you are not allowed to see this, you are too young.");
  } else {
    alert("Welcome " + name + ", you are " + age + " visit our lounge!");
  }
}
```